# batch apex rollup on lookup relationship

Tags: apex, batch

public class RollUpSummary implements Database.Batchable, Schedulable {

```
//Invocable Method
@InvocableMethod(label='Rollup Amounts added in salaries')
public static void rollupSalaries(List<Salary__c> salaries) {
    rollupSalaries(salaries);
}

//Batchable Methods
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,Total_Salary__c FROM Candidate__c]);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Candidate__c> batch){
    Set<Id> CanIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Candidate__c can : batch) {
        CanIds.add(can.Id);
    }

    summarizeSalaries(CanIds);
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {}

//Schedulable Methods
public void execute(SchedulableContext context){
    RollUpSummary batchJob = new RollUpSummary();
    Database.executeBatch(batchJob);
}

//Static Methods
public static void rollupSummaries(List<Salary__c> salaries) {
    Set<Id> CanIds = new Set<Id>();

    //Get account Ids from specified opportunities
    for (Salary__c sal : salaries) {
        CanIds.add(sal.Monthly_Salary__c);
    }

    if (CanIds.isEmpty() == false) {
        /*Execute as a future call so that the user doesn't have to wait around for
        the rollup to finish. Unless, already in a future or batch call state then
        just perform the rollup.*/
        if (System.isFuture() == false && System.isBatch() == false) {
            summarizeSalariesAsync(CanIds);
        }
        else {
            new RollUpSummary().summarizeSalaries(CanIds);
        }
    }
}

@future
public static void summarizeSalariesAsync(Set<Id> CanIds) {
    new RollUpSummary().summarizeSalaries(CanIds);
}

//Public Methods
public void summarizeSalaries(Set<Id> CanIds) {
    //Get Accounts to Update
    List<Candidate__c> candidates = queryCandidatesById(CanIds);

    Map<Id, double> results = getAmountsByMonthly_Salary(CanIds);

    //Loop Accounts and set Won Amount
    List<Candidate__c> candidatesToUpdate = new List<Candidate__c>();
    for (Candidate__c cand : candidates) {
        double total = 0;

        if (results.containsKey(cand.Id)) {
            total = results.get(cand.Id);
        }

        //Determine if Total Amount has Changed
        if (cand.Total_Salary__c != total) {
            cand.Total_Salary__c = total;
            candidatesToUpdate.add(cand); //Add account to collection to be updated
        }
    }

    if(candidatesToUpdate.isEmpty() == false) {
        Database.SaveResult[] saveResults = Database.update(candidatesToUpdate, false);
        System.debug(saveResults);
    }
}

//Private Methods
public Map<Id, double> getAmountsByMonthly_Salary(Set<Id> CanIds) {
    Map<Id, double> resultsByMonthly_Salary = new Map<Id, double>();

    //Summarize Amounts by Account Id
    AggregateResult[] results = aggregateAmounts(CanIds);
    for (AggregateResult result : results) {
        Id CandId = (Id) result.get('SalaryId');
        double total = (double) result.get('Total');

        resultsByMonthly_Salary.put(CandId, total);
    }
    return resultsByMonthly_Salary;
}

//Query Methods
private List<Candidate__c> queryCandidatesById(Set<Id> CanIds) {
    return [SELECT 
            Id 
            ,Total_Salary__c
        FROM 
            Candidate__c 
        WHERE 
            Id IN :CanIds];
}

private AggregateResult[] aggregateOpportunityAmounts(Set<Id> CanIds) {
    return [SELECT 
             Monthly_Salary__c SalaryId
            ,SUM(Amount__c) Total 
        FROM 
            Salary__c
           where
            Monthly_Salary__c IN :CanIds
        GROUP BY 
            Monthly_Salary__c];
}
```

}

Comment: I am getting the the following error:Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void aggregateAmounts(Set<Id>) from the type RollUpSummary

Answer (score 1):

> The method definition is given by the name
>   `aggregateOpportunityAmounts` whereas you are calling the method by a
>   different name i.e. `aggregateAmounts`

Use same names for calling and defining the method.

Comment: ohh...thanks .now i am getting these errors:Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void rollupSalaries(List<Salary__c>) from the type RollUpSummaryMethod does not exist or incorrect signature: void rollupSalaries(List<Salary__c>) from the type RollUpSummary

Comment: Same problem: you have defined the method with the name: rollupSummaries instead of rollupSalaries